# how to decode a hashcode password when post in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am running a script for login a site in jmeter where the credentials for the password is hashcode and in encrypted format. like this below as java library are used like validation of password, I am not able to write the java code for converting the decrypt the password

Actual what post data displayed:

```
&member_login_number=test@gmail.com&member_login_password=0d42afb79ebef4fbf34989341c42ca40dd3504d5da60c8eeffaf73d169e77c63601c72a4cda2c706e2b4e15a84dc8d50e024ab1b2e6198d94d0ae70c57de1808
```

CSV Data Config

username :testing@test.com

Password:password

Now when i using the csv data config to parameterized the password with the 
actual password request is not getting success even after entering the 
hashcode password to csvfile the post is not successful.

Is there any solution for this?

Screenshots below:

[image: CSV DataConfig]

[username_password_request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBMuw.png)

Comment: how your csv data config configured? show example of row in csv also

Comment: A hash function is a **one-way** transform. You don't reverse it. Instead hash the local password and check that the hashes match.

Comment: The entire point of hashing the password is that it can not be decoded. Otherwise, hashing provides no security.

Comment: i have added the screenshot for  reference.

Comment: your script should properly authenticate, using username and password, just like normal user would, and not try to use previous hash.

Comment: @KirilS. : i did try the same using username as well password and even updated the hashcode password to verify whether it is achieving success or not but no luck.. tried all possible scenario

Comment: do you login within your script?

Comment: @KirilS. : yes i do have but still there issue exits do i need to write the code for that, i m adding screenshot

Comment: I have also added the regular expression to get the password from the placeholder and check if this is getting work but currently this is not happening @Dmitri : is it possible for you to help me

Comment: @user7294900 : Please check i have added the screenshot of the csv in jmeter and the username and password